# Javascript DIV not updating on change

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make a page where the usere can chose between two products and enter some text in two  fields which will append on the end of a link. My page works If I enter the text first and then chose the option however if I select the product option first the text doesn't append and if I try to update the text in the fields once the link is shown, it remains the same. I'm a bit of a beginner to JavaScript so any suggestions as to where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated?

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function productChange(product) {
            var val = product.value
            var idTag = document.getElementById("idTag");
            var trackingTag = document.getElementById("trackingTag");

            if (val == 'Movies') {
               document.getElementById('divProductChangeLinkTitle').innerHTML = '<span style="color: #680091;">Your movies link is:</span>';
               document.getElementById('divProductChangeFinalMovLink').innerHTML = 'https://www.link/MOVIES?cid=' + idTag.value + '&omniture=' + trackingTag.value;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('divProductChangeLinkTitle').innerHTML = '<span style="color: #FF7000;">Your ents link is:</span>';
                document.getElementById('divProductChangeFinalMovLink').innerHTML = 'https://www.link/ENTS?cid=' + idTag.value + '&omniture=' + trackingTag.value;

            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Movies: <input name="ProductRadio" type="radio" value="Movies" onclick='productChange(this)' id="MoviesRadio" /><br>
    Ents: <input name="ProductRadio" type="radio" value="Entertainment" onclick='productChange(this)' id="EntsRadio" />
    <br><br>
    ID: <input type="text" id="idTag" onchange="productChange()"><br>
    Tracking: <input type="text" id="trackingTag" onchange="productChange()">
    <br><br>
    <div align="center" id="divProductChangeLinkTitle"></div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="divProductChangeFinalMovLink" style="color: #000000;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method, when onChange event occurs for input text, then val is undefined, because you are not passing anything, so in productChange() method, you can get radio button values directly, I have made some changes in your code, please check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zr3ntxhz/) -

HTML -

```
Movies: <input name="ProductRadio" type="radio" value="Movies" onclick='productChange()' id="MoviesRadio" /><br>
Ents: <input name="ProductRadio" type="radio" value="Entertainment" onclick='productChange()' id="EntsRadio" />
<br><br>
ID: <input type="text" id="idTag" onchange="productChange()"><br>
Tracking: <input type="text" id="trackingTag" onchange="productChange()">
<br><br>
<div align="center" id="divProductChangeLinkTitle"></div>
<br><br>
<div id="divProductChangeFinalMovLink" style="color: #000000;"></div>
```

Javascript -

```
function productChange() {

        var val = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="ProductRadio"]:checked').value; 
        var idTag = document.getElementById("idTag").value;
        var trackingTag = document.getElementById("trackingTag").value; 

        if (val == 'Movies' && idTag && trackingTag) {
           document.getElementById('divProductChangeLinkTitle').innerHTML = '<span style="color: #680091;">Your movies link is:</span>';
           document.getElementById('divProductChangeFinalMovLink').innerHTML = 'https://www.link/MOVIES?cid=' + idTag + '&omniture=' + trackingTag;
        } else if(val=='Entertainment'  && idTag && trackingTag){
            document.getElementById('divProductChangeLinkTitle').innerHTML = '<span style="color: #FF7000;">Your ents link is:</span>';
            document.getElementById('divProductChangeFinalMovLink').innerHTML = 'https://www.link/ENTS?cid=' + idTag + '&omniture=' + trackingTag;

        }
    }
```

Now, if radio button is selected and both inputs have some value then only link will be shown

Answer (score 0):

Hey the above code is working , but you to also set one condition to check atleast one radio button then fill the input values else on direct filling those input text fields it is giving error. 
So one radio button needs to be checked.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function productChange(product) {
            var val = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="ProductRadio"]:checked').value; 
            var idTag = document.getElementById("idTag");
            var trackingTag = document.getElementById("trackingTag");

            if (val == 'Movies') {
               document.getElementById('divProductChangeLinkTitle').innerHTML = '<span style="color: #680091;">Your movies link is:</span>';
               document.getElementById('divProductChangeFinalMovLink').innerHTML = 'https://www.link/MOVIES?cid=' + idTag.value + '&omniture=' + trackingTag.value;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('divProductChangeLinkTitle').innerHTML = '<span style="color: #FF7000;">Your ents link is:</span>';
                document.getElementById('divProductChangeFinalMovLink').innerHTML = 'https://www.link/ENTS?cid=' + idTag.value + '&omniture=' + trackingTag.value;

            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Movies: <input name="ProductRadio" type="radio" value="Movies" onclick='productChange(this)' id="MoviesRadio" /><br>
    Ents: <input name="ProductRadio" type="radio" value="Entertainment" onclick='productChange(this)' id="EntsRadio" />
    <br><br>
    ID: <input type="text" id="idTag" onchange="productChange()"><br>
    Tracking: <input type="text" id="trackingTag" onchange="productChange()">
    <br><br>
    <div align="center" id="divProductChangeLinkTitle"></div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="divProductChangeFinalMovLink" style="color: #000000;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You need to pass value while calling productChange function.